# Can Swagger have different security for different tags?

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0

Can Swagger have different security for different tags? I can't find the setting for tag's security in the Swagger Specification.

I hope the same tag will own the same security, and different tags will own different security.

I know paths can set their own security, but it's a little inconvenient.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

`security` can be set either globally or in individual operations (GET/POST/etc.), with the operation-level `security` overriding the global `security`.

Refer to the specification to see what is supported and what's not:
https://github.com/OAI/OpenAPI-Specification/blob/master/versions/2.0.md

Comment: Thank you for your help.
Btw,thanks for edit my question,there are lots of spelling mistakes.I will improve my Englsh~ ;) 谢谢！